# draw a different form of date using canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw a different form of date , like that :

1. 2019/01/07
2. 2019.01.07
3. 2019-01-07
4. ۲۰۱۹/۰۱/۰٧
5. ۲۰۱۹.۰۱.۰٧
6. ۲۰۱۹-۰۱-۰٧
7. 2019 January 07 (using different Languages)

Code:

```
function click() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var carta = new Image();
    carta.src = "national.jpg"
    var t_milade = document.getElementById("t_milade").value;
    carta.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(carta, 0, 0, 728, 546);
        context.font = "900 35px Alfa Slab One";
        context.fillStyle = "#181818";
        context.textAlign = "right";
        context.fillText(t_milade, 262, 440);
    }  
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks, but I do not know how I can use it